# How to get time elapsed since program start?

Tags: c#

I am currently developing a C# application and I don't know how to get the program's timestamp.

I tried using the following code:

```cs
public string GetTimeStamp()
   {
      return DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.ToUnixTimeSeconds().ToString();
   }

private async void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {

      Clipboard.SetText(ts);
   }
```

But I end up with this:

```
1580565803
```

I expected something like this: (In the programs time from start counting up.)

```
000000
or
000050
```

So I could format it like this:

```
00:00:50
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch` too to get elapsed milliseconds.

Like this :

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
        stopWatch.Start();
        Thread.Sleep(10000);
        long elapsedTime = stopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
        Console.WriteLine("RunTime " + elapsedTime);
    }
}
```

More info [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stopwatch?view=netframework-4.8).

Answer (score 0):

To get the number of seconds elapsed since the application was opened, you will need to subtract the date of the process being started from the current date, and then using modulo division and regular division to get your timestamp (padding it with 0s for aesthetic value):

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        int seconds = (int)Math.Floor((DateTime.UtcNow - Process.GetCurrentProcess().StartTime.ToUniversalTime()).TotalSeconds);

        int timestampSeconds = seconds % 60;
        int timestampMinutes = (int)Math.Floor((double)(seconds / 60)) % 60;
        int timestampHours = (int)Math.Floor((double)(seconds / 3600));
        Console.WriteLine(timestampHours.ToString() + ":" +
                          timestampMinutes.ToString().PadLeft(2, '0') + ":" +
                          timestampSeconds.ToString().PadLeft(2, '0'));
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

To get how long in seconds your program has run, you would have to save a timestamp when you start your code. Then when you want to calculate how long your code has run for, calculate the current timestamp and take `currrentTimestamp - startTimestamp`

Comment: There is no need to save a timestamp. C# provides information on the start time of the current process.